# How to get JSF (Mojarra) 1.2 working on TomEE 7 (Plus or PluME)?

Tags: jsf-1.2, mojarra, tomee-7

I'm deploying a Java EE application using JSF (Mojarra) 1.2 and Seam 2.2.2.
It works on JBoss EAP 7.0.0 and Oracle WebLogic 12.2.1.
However I cannot get it working on TomEE 7.0.2 (Plus nor PluME).

Simple WEB application for problem reproduction is available [here](https://github.com/atosconsulting/tomee-jsf12-seam22-issue).

I will be very glad for any suggestion how to get Mojarra 1.2 working on TomEE 7 (any edition).

Comment: I will have a look, but your POM.xml scares me. Why do you include hibernate as a provided dependency and not work with JPA directly ? Sames goes for other dependencies el-api. Just use JavaEE-7 api dependency :)

Comment: Thanks for the good point about pom.xml: I merged few POMs into one and I did it incorrectly. I re-did it after reading your comment and now it's better reflecting the original POMs. As you can see, it's a legacy application from pre-JavaEE era - so no javaee-api dependency (its presence was a side effect of my incorrect merge).


BTW, I'm not an author of the POM nor the app - I've only extracted a sample of a real app into a mini-app which can be easily deployed and which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: IHMO, it seems you're riding a dead horse. It's not expected that JSF 1.x support will be ported back to latest JEE7 containers. Did you consider upgrading the application step by step towards JSF 2.x?

Comment: The horse is not yet dead as it's running on most recent JBoss EAP and Oracle WebLogic ;)
It seems that authors and owners of the application are happy with it as it works well (BTW, I'm not an author - just a deployer). JSF 1.2 is enforced by Seam and RichFaces which are used in the application. Upgrade of JSF means re-creation of the whole web layer and it cannot be justified from the business perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved - JSF Mojarra 1.2 works on TomEE Plus 7.0.2 :)

**What is done**

Removal of the following libraries:

- myfaces-api-2.2.11.jar
- myfaces-impl-2.2.11.jar
- openwebbeans-jsf-1.7.0.jar
- tomee-mojarra-7.0.2.jar
- tomee-myfaces-7.0.2.jar

Addition of the following libraries (from Maven repo):

- jsf-api-1.2_12.jar
- jsf-impl-1.2_12.jar
- openwebbeans-jsf12-1.6.3.jar
- openwebbeans-el10-1.6.3.jar

In addition some corrections of JSF pages were done to make them XHTML-compliant -- TomEE breaks rendering on incorrect XHTML (i.e. not closed tags) while other app servers don't have problem with that.